# How can i add success in place of done and error in place of fail

Tags: ajax

How can i add success in place of done and error in place of fail?

```
$.ajax({url: "/plugins/custom/cisco/${url_node}/custom.cisco.endpoint-test-28?DOB=28-02-1994&month=Feb", 
        type:"POST"}).done(function(data){
              $('#test_macro').hide();
                 console.log("Data :", data);
              }).fail(function(error){
                 console.log('Error');
            });

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/plugins/custom/cisco/${url_node}/custom.cisco.endpoint-test-28?DOB=28-02-1994&month=Feb",
    type:"POST",
    success: function(data){
        $('#test_macro').hide();
        console.log("Data :", data);
    },
    error: function(data){
        console.log('Error');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Be ware of the deprecation notice starting from JQuery 3.0:

> Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

You can use it as the following:

```
  var jqxhr = $.ajax( {
  method: "POST",
  url: "/plugins/custom/cisco/${url_node}/custom.cisco.endpoint-test-28?DOB=28-02-1994&month=Feb",
  data: { name: "Dummy"  }//in case you want to post data, 
  } )
  .done(function(data) {
    $('#test_macro').hide();
    console.log("Data :", data);
    alert( "success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "complete" );
  });
```

Always check the official documentation:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

$.ajax({
    url: "/plugins/custom/cisco/${url_node}/custom.cisco.endpoint-test-28?DOB=28-02-1994&month=Feb",
    type:"POST",
    success: function(data){
        $('#test_macro').hide();
        console.log("Data :", data);
    },
    error: function(data){
        console.log('Error');
    }
})